# R - Best way to apply function to long list

Tags: r

I have a long list object (length in the millions).  I would like to apply a function to each entry in the list and then return a new augmented list.  Aside from looping from 1 to the length of the list, what would be the best and most efficient way to accomplish this?  An example of this is below along with the loop I'm currently using.

```
list1 <- list("zzz yyy xxx", "zzz yyy rrr", "rrr jjj ppp", "eee bbb ccc", "qqq pppp zzz")

change <- function(entry) {
    entry <- strsplit(entry, " ")[[1]]
    aug_entry <- entry[!entry %in% 'zzz']
    return(aug_entry)
}
```

I'm looking for a better alternative to this...

```
list2 <- list()
for (j in 1:length(list1)) {
    list2[[j]] <- change(list1[[j]])
}
```

I've looked online and can't seem to find a good solution to this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `lapply(strsplit(unlist(list1)," "),setdiff,"zzz")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I should have provided a better example.  The function I'm trying to apply is actually quite a bit more complicated than simply removing the 'zzz.'  In reality I'm trying to clean some text so I should have provided an example where I change 'zzz' to 'zz.'  Is there an efficient way to apply a function to a list that I'm not using?

Comment: You could also do something like `lapply(list1, gsub, pattern = "zzz", replacement = "zz")` and avoid the splitting....

Comment: Provide a realistic example. It doesn't make sense that `list1` is a `list`, since each element is of length one; a character vector is better (that's why I used `unlist` in my comment). Edit your question stating your real problem and you very likely will have a useful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think `lapply` is what you are looking for. With your example, you can get the output with this

```
list2<- lapply(list1,function(x)change(x))
```